# NSArray or NSDictionary for storing in UserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I've a collection of a usertype News currently stored in a NSArray. I have to store them in UserDefaults to save them on the Device. A News have a property ID which is unique. Before storing them to UserDefaults, I convert the NSArray to a NSDictionary where the key is the ID and the object for this key is the News. Is this a good way to store them?

The reason for choosing an NSDictionary is to be able to check if a News with a specific ID exists in the list of News each time I redownload the News from a Web Service. This way I have only one News instance for each News ID. I think this would be hard to manage using a normal NSArray -- or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have to store them in UserDefaults to save them on the Device.

UserDefaults are for storing preferences, settings and other "small" bit of information, they are not for storing application data. You do not "have" to use NSUserDefaults, there are many other options available to you. Writing to files (in the document directory) in their original form or using NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver for example.

You can get the document directory path like this

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Apart from that storing an NSDictionary with News ids as keys is fine. I don't really see the point of having an NSArray and "converting" it to an NSDictionary, use one or the other (that way you always ensure that you only have one News per item).

Comment: Is I read the guidelines from Apple regarding Data Storage, it seems that the files should be saved in `/Library/Caches` instead of `/Documents`: http://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/. Is it correct?

Comment: If you read your own link, it says Caches if you can re-create the data, Documents if you cannot re-create the data. Because the cache data can be removed, so if it's critical user data, the user will not be happy at all...

Comment: In my case it is News objects downloaded from my WebService -- like a mapping of my database. These data could be re-downloaded, so I think that my data should be in the `Caches`.

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` is not a database, but you already knew it.

Anyway, I'd store the array directly and also save the last seen news ID as a separate *preference*. Then, you only need to process news items with ID greater than the last seen item.  When you download news items you need to update both the news and the last seen ID. You need to guarantee that IDs are in ascending order.

A different approach, depending on your particular use of news, would be to save two arrays, one with the news items and a different one with the list of news IDs. Use the second array to  check if there are fresh news.

Unless you are handling lot of news items (in which case you should use Core Data anyway) you are optimizing something that doesn't need optimization. Reading, sorting, updating and saving back a small array into `NSUserDefaults` is pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks! I think that I need to store the News collection elsewhere -- I see the point that UserDefault is not made for that. I found this guide: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/.

Is this the right way to go?

Comment: If the volume of news is small (hundreds) and there are no relationships with other pieces of data, I recommend NSKeyedArchiver, as jbat100 told you in his answer. Also, it's easier to get it right the first time than with Core Data.

Comment: Can you provide me with a tutorial for how to implement NSKeyedArchiver? I have implemented the NSCoding prototype for my News class, but I need information on how to store them on the device.

Comment: I did the storing using the archiveRootObject method in NSKeyedArchiver. Which file extensions is common to use?

Comment: You can use .archive or whatever extension fits your problem domain. Check the "Archives and Serializations Programming Guide" and "CopyPasteTitle" sample, both in Xcode documentation.